# MySQL and PHP search for similar words

Tags: php, mysql, select

My MySQL table contains items which have the attributes name(name of item) and keywords(words related to the item). I search the database with the following code..

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE (name LIKE '%$query%' OR keywords LIKE '%$query%') LIMIT $start, $per_page"
```

One item is a phone and it has a keyword "mobile", so when someone searches mobile the item appears as a result which is fine. But when someone searches "mobiles" with the s on the end it displays no results. How can I make my query search for anything that includes the search term?

Comment: How many items do you have in your table? I can suggest you 2 things: MyISAM / Aria FULLTEXT search OR... something Lucene based like ElasticSearch/SolR.

Comment: I have hundreds to thousands of items in my table :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this was down-voted due to lack of detail, I am editing with an explanation.

The Like operator matches a strict pattern of characters with some wildcard characters.  What you are asking the database to do is interpret natural language variants on search terms to account for things like plurals.  You cannot do that with pattern matching alone.  There is no good, reliable way to match on a part of a search term with the Like or similar operator (we can write code to remove any trailing spaces in the search in an attempt to match on more items, for example).  I recommend you research the following, a capability common to all major RDBMS platforms such as MS SQL:

Natural Language Full-Text Searches:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

That link is a reference to the feature complete with sample code.

Comment: I think this may be the solution to my problem just need to try it out. :) and im not sure why someone down voted it and i dont have the reputation to vote it up or down :(

Comment: I made an attempt to improve the answer.  I hope you are able to resolve your problem.  Thanks!